# what the "welcome son" means in this sentence?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> The 37-year-old royal - who welcomed son Archie Harrison
>   Mountbatten-Windsor with husband Prince Harry earlier this year - is
>   reportedly planning to become a published author

Is the grammar of that sentence standard(true)? .I searched everywhere for "welcome son" but I didn't find anything.

Comment: The article is talking about Duchess Meghan. She welcomed HER son Archie earlier this year, she gave birth to him two months ago. The determiner "her" has been omitted.

Comment: First of all, the article says ***welcomed*** *son*, not ***welcome*** *son*.

Comment: It reads like a sentence written by a journalist in a hurry. It is not ungrammatical but it is not easy to read.